# Pagination django

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have a view related to the index.html

in the view I have a form to filter a query , and a table where i put the elements i got from the query

Recently I added a pagination because some times the query can have thousands of results.

I used the example shown here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/pagination/

If I use the form and make a query I got the data paginated, but if I click next I lost the data I had in the form, so the query change

The problem I see is that the form respond to a POST method, but clicking "next" produce a request with GET method, so when   `form = FilterForm(request.POST)` is executed, the form is valid, but empty

Thanks

EDIT:

example code of the view

```
if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...

    form = FilterForm(request.POST)  # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid():
        total_events_list = Make the Query
else:
    form = FilterForm()  # An unbound form
    total_events_list = Make another Query

paginator = Paginator(total_events_list, PAGE_LIMIT, orphans=9)


try:
    latest_events_list = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    latest_events_list = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    latest_events_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


context = {'latest_events_list': latest_events_list, 'form': form}
return render_to_response('db_interface/index.html', context,   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The template , the form to filter the query

```
<p> Filter events </p>
<form action="/db_interface/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    FORM
<input type="submit" name ="filter" value="Submit" />
</form>


{% if latest_events_list %}

 <form action="indexzip" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for event in latest_events_list %}
   SHOW DATA
  {% endfor %}

   <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
        {% if latest_events_list.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ latest_events_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

         <span class="current">
         Page {{ latest_events_list.number }} of {{ latest_events_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
         </span>

         {% if latest_events_list.has_next %}
          <a href="?page={{ latest_events_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
         {% endif %}
          </span>
         </div>

  </form>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use GET throughout? I mean if it's just about filtering, POST as a REST verb doesn't make much sense anyway, because it doesn't alter any data. See here: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I made a test using GET. The problem is that the page doesnt load the initial values on the form now, and the original problem continue

Comment: But you can pass the form values inside the view function/html template! And in the pagination links you just add those filter values to the query string.

Comment: Sorry,  I didnt get how to do  : " And in the pagination links you just add those filter values to the query string"

Comment: In <a href='?page {{latest_events_list.previous_page_number}}{{filters}}'>previous</a>: for 'filters' you can pass in that which initially was input in the filter form.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your query somewhere, because its needed every time you make pagination request. There could be three ways to do that:
1. Make Ajax requests and pass form data as well along with page number to pagination request.
2. Create a cookie/session and store your query in it and re-use it when needed.
3. Create a cookie/session and store your query data in it and manually slice the data.
Personally, I would recommend the 1st first option as it makes more sense then creating cookies/sessions. Plus they have limited sizes as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <form action='' method='GET'>
        <type="search" name='query'>
        </form>
        from django.core.paginator import Paginator
        from django.shortcuts import render
        def get_query(request):
              template='xxx,yy.html'
              obj=A.objects.all()
              query=request.GET.get('query',None)
              page=request.GET.get('page',None)
              if not page or not query:
                 page=1
                 query=''
              obj=obj.filter(param_icontains=query)
              paginator=Paginator(obj,3)
              obj=paginator.page(page)
              return render(request,templete,{'obj':obj})
```

Comment: If there is no security issue then u can use http method for form as GET.This will display the query key value on the page adress field.